# If $x^{8^{-8^{x}}}=8$, then find $\sqrt[3x]{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can not find a simple algebraic manipulation to arrive at what is requested:

If  $x^{8^{-8^{x}}}=8$, then find $\sqrt[3x]{x}$

Comment: HINT: use $8^a=8^b$ if and only if $a=b$. Note that $8=8^1$ and $1=8^0$. Can you go on with this?

Comment: It looks to me that $x^{8^{-8^x}}\lt8$ for all $x$, so the question makes no sense, really.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^{8^{-8^x}}=8$. Taking logarithms gives

\begin{align*}
8^{-8^x}\ln x&=\ln 8\\
\frac{1}{8^{8^x}}\ln x&=\ln 8\\
\Rightarrow\ln x&=8^{8^x}\ln 8\\
\Rightarrow\ln x&=\ln 8^{8^{8^x}}\\
\Rightarrow x&=\exp(\ln 8^{8^{8^x}})\\
\Rightarrow x&=8^{8^{8^x}}
\end{align*}
Let $a=8^{8^x}$ so that $x=8^a$, and noting $8=2^3$ gives
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3x]{x}&=(8^a)^{1/3x}\\
&=(2^{3a})^{1/3x}\\
&=2^{\frac{3a}{3x}}\\
&=2^{\frac{a}{x}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Does the equation $x=8^{8^{8^x}}$ have any (real) solutions?

Comment: If we plug in $x=8^{8^{8^x}}$ recursively we next get $x=8^{8^{8^{8^{8^{8^x}}}}}$, with the number of $8$s in the chain doubling each time, starting $3$, $6$, $12$, etc. So there can be no real results as the whole thing blows up, and my result is merely a formal manipulation. (If $u+iv=8^{8^{8^{u+iv}}}$ we have the same problem. So there can be no complex solutions either.)